# What is the name for the point where a non-smooth transition occurs

Tags: terminology

In the question [Smooth transition between two lines (2d)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45321/smooth-transition-between-two-lines-2d?newreg=d2d747c8fa3842c3bd32e59b982cfa9b) there is an example of a composite curve which has a point where it is non-smooth.

In general, what is the name for that transition point?

Answer (score 1):

The most general concept/word would be [singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_point_of_a_curve).

In this case, I might call it a "corner", a concept which can be made formal with the concept of a "smooth manifold with corners" as mentioned [in this MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/801819/26369), for instance.

Depending on the context/exact situation, something like this may be called a [cusp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cusp_(singularity)) or [crunode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crunode).